# set value of dropdown on type/autocomplete using selectize js input

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using [selectize js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to populate country data (from db) as a dropdown. this dropdown is working fine on `onChange`, `onload`.

I'm trying to append a dropdown option on the following condition: user queries for "us", "usa" or "united states". In this case it should return 'united states' as country from db.

I'm returning a json object with 'united states' when user types 'us' or 'usa', 'united' but it doesn't populate in autocomplete:

```
country_selector = $('#data_country').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name'],
    options: [],
    create: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    openOnFocus: true,
    closeAfterSelect: false,
    preload: true,
    highlight: false,
    render: {
        option: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div class="game-section--country-list--selected-country" data-country = "' + item.id + '" id = "game-selected-country"><span class = "game-section--country-list--name" > ' + item.name + '</span>' + '</div>';
        },
        item: function (item, escape) {
            return '<div class="game-section--country-list--selected-country" data-country = "' + item.id + '" id = "game-selected-country"><span class = "game-section--country-list--name" > ' + item.name + '</span>' + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {

        var selectize = this;
        var form_data = {
            'q': query,
            'action': 'countries'
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: game_section_ajax_object.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form_data,
            error: function () {
                callback();
            },
            success: function (res) {

                /*here i m adding new element to json on condtion when q = 'us or usa or united*/
                res.countries.push(
                    { id: "US", name: "United States" }
                );
                callback(res.countries);


                /*but it doesnt append united states in dropdown on autocompelte*/


            }
        }
            });

        },

)}
```

I expect the dropdown options to show "united states" when user type any of below keyword "us", "usa", "united states".